# Is it possible to Capture a Video directly into an SQL database using MediaCapture in WinRT?

Tags: c#, database, windows-runtime, webcam

Don't think it's possible but would like to confirm? I am guessing you have to use MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync method. Which will record it into the file system. Then you can transfer it from the file system into a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can record to a non-file based stream as well with MediaCapture.[StartRecordToStreamAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700868.aspx) and you may be able to wire that stream to your SQL database without saving to a file first.

How exactly you'd wire it up depends on what sort of database connection you are using and if and how it can consume a stream. Windows Runtime doesn't have a built-in SQL database. Typically one uses a local database such as SQLite or a remote database through a web service. For the latter you can use the recording stream as the source for an [HttpStreamContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpstreamcontent.aspx).

Comment: I am building an enterprise application. I am side loading the application and connecting to some .net code via a brokered windows run-time component. This enterprise code uses nHibernate and SQLServer. I am starting to highly doubt what I am trying to achieve is possible. 

Even if it is possible... I think performance wise it would be better to just store it locally on the file system.